# Accessing WCF Service Root File

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service which needs to read a file that sits in the same folder and I am not sure on how to get the file path.

Have tried: `string filePath = Path.GetFullPath("T.sql");` which gives me something like C:\Program Files\IIS Express\T.SQL which is wrong.

What is the correct syntax to get the file path?

Comment: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "/T.sql";
```

Comment: @sd_dracula - no problem - however, I'd be wary of loading SQL into an application and then executing it - this is how sql injection attacks happen!